# How to find shared memory size of the docker container?

Tags: docker, shared-memory

Is there a way to access shm-size from inside the docker container?

`shm-size` is an optional parameter in the `docker run`
For e.g.

```
docker run -it --shm-size=256m oracle11g /bin/bash
```

However, how do I access the size from inside the docker container? is there an environment variable that's exposed by docker to fetch the shared memory information?

Answer (score 1):

You can inspect the property of your container with the [inspect command.](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/inspect/)

```bash
docker inspect CONTAINER_ID -f '{{ .HostConfig.ShmSize }}'
```

Also, you can replace by the name of the container

Comment: This should be marked as the accepted answer